# Android camera saving images both in portrait and landscape mode

Tags: android, image, camera, landscape-portrait

I am making an android app and i want to use the camera in that. I implemened the code properly but the problem that I am facing is that the image that i capture is saved twice, one as horizontal and the other as vertical. This is a weird problem and I am not able to figure it out. The folllowing is the code that I am using.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                FaceconActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Share a Photo");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (item == 0) {
                    values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "New Picture");
                    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION,
                            "From your Camera");
                    imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(
                            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                            values);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, PICTURE_RESULT);
                } else if (item == 1) {
                    try {
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        startActivityForResult(
                                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
                                PICK_IMAGE);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
```

and

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case PICK_IMAGE:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                try {
                    // OI FILE Manager
                    String filemanagerstring = selectedImageUri.getPath();
                    // MEDIA GALLERY
                    String selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                    if (selectedImagePath != null) {
                        filePath = selectedImagePath;
                    } else if (filemanagerstring != null) {
                        filePath = filemanagerstring;
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unknown path",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.e("Bitmap", "Unknown path");
                    }

                    if (filePath != null) {
                        decodeFile(filePath);
                    } else {
                        bitmap = null;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Internal error",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
                }
            }
            break;
        case PICTURE_RESULT:
            if (requestCode == PICTURE_RESULT)
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    try {
                        thumbnail = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                                getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                        imageurl = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri);
                        decodeFile(imageurl);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
        }
    }
```

Can anyone please help me??
-Thanks in advace

Comment: I dont think I was facing this problem earlier. Can it be because of the android update. I update my cell from 2.3.4 to 2.3.6.

Comment: Update : It seems that it was a device problem, because the same code worked perfectly fine in other devices.

Answer (score 0):

in item ==o please use the below working code:::

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),(cal.getTimeInMillis()+".jpg"));
if(!file.exists()){
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}else{
    file.delete();
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
startActivityForResult(i, PICTURE_RESULT);
```

also you can change the image name as you like